# Error in login model

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to create login. But on checking the credentials from database it is logging if any1 data is correct and other is incorrect also.
for login- name, email, mobile all are allowed.
'status' should be 'active' is an extra condition.
What am I doing wrong??

```
function login($username, $password) {
    $where = "status='active' AND name='$username' OR email_id= '$username' OR mobile_no='$username' AND password ='trim($password)'";
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('user_details');
    $this->db->where($where);
    //$this->db->where('password', trim($password));
    $this->db->limit(1);

    $query = $this->db->get();
    if ($query->num_rows() == 1) {
        return $query->result();
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Set the OR statments in brackets () like:
"status='active' AND (name='$username' OR email_id= '$username' OR mobile_no='$username') AND password ='trim($password)'"

And i hope you escape the user inputs, otherwise your code is vulnerable for sql-injection

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use query grouping using `group_start()` and `group_end()`.No fear of `SQL Injection`.

```
$this->db->select('*')->from('user_details')
            ->where('status', 'active')
            ->group_start()
                    ->where('email_id',$username )
                    ->or_where('mobile_no',$username)
            ->group_end()
    ->where('password',trim($password))
->limit(1)
->get();
```

for more see here [Codeigniter Query Builder](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#query-grouping)

Answer (score 1):

You have issue in where clause. You need to use parenthesis to check the columns with OR.

Please check below.

```
 $where = "status='active' AND
      (name='$username' OR email_id= '$username' OR mobile_no='$username')
       AND password ='trim($password)'";
```